# Difference Between OmniAuth Implementations for Facebook and Twitter

Tags: facebook, twitter, oauth, omniauth

I'm a bit confused about how omniauth works for facebook and twitter. I notice when I use twitter, then I end up getting back credentials which include a token and a secret. My understanding is that twitter will return the same set of keys for the same application keys.

For facebook I notice that I only get back a single token. I would like to use this token to identify the user when they use my application-- but my concern is that since I am only getting one token back, that this is a short lived token which might change.

I did some research to find out if Twitter supports OAuth 1.0 (which I'm quite certain Twitter uses).

Am I missing something? Is a it a matter of Twitter and Facebook using different OAuth versions.

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like to use this token to identify the user when they use my application"? You can identify a user by the `provider` and `uid` fields.

Comment: @Ashitaka - thanks-- I see what you mean-- I guess I'm kind of confusing authentication for authorization- if my goal is to identify the user, then the uid and provider should be all that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter and Facebook do, in fact, use different versions of OAuth. Twitter uses OAuth 1.0A, while Facebook uses OAuth 2.0. These versions have different implementations.

For Twitter, there are two options for accessing the APIs via OAuth, application-only auth and application-user auth.

For details on Twitter's OAuth, check out https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth

For details on how to obtain access tokens for Twitter APIs: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens